# How to set a span in JS instead of making a alert

Tags: javascript, html

Kind of a newbie to this but I have followed a totorial on a memory game as an attempt to understand the syntax of JS but am stuck on making the round result print in a  instead of showing up as a alert
here is a codepen [here](https://codepen.io/Person2356/pen/qBpeMpB).

how can I print round in a `<span> <!-- result here--> </span>` rather than like this `alert("result")`

How can I make it set to a span instead of being an alert?

Comment: Please make a [example] (with emphasis on "minimal"). Is your question simply "I want to show a string in a span rather than in an alert. Here is my HTML: `<span><span>`, i had `alert("foo")`, how to put `"foo"` in this span instead?"

Comment: thanks @Amadan working on it now, like I siad, new to this

Comment: No worries, I saw you are new on Stack Overflow. But you will get much better answers much sooner if your question is concise and precise, asking about one narrow and easily identified problem, rather than if we have to hunt for what you are asking in multiple screens of irrelevant code.

Comment: @Amadan thanks so much, is what I have done now better?

Comment: Are you trying to say is: You want to have the result shown in the HTML SPAN rather than in the alert box?

Comment: @NiqueJoe yes, sorry if that was unclear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers parse HTML into a tree of objects called [Document Object Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) (DOM). Using JavaScript you can query the DOM to get individual nodes, and then change them.

To get your span, you would typically use `document.getElementById` or `document.querySelector` (there are other functions that can fetch collections of related nodes, like `document.getElementsByClassName` or `document.querySelectorAll`). The former identify nodes by the property named in the method name (ID, or class name, respectively); the latter ones use [CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors). (All of the `getElement...` functions can be replicated using the newer `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` interface, though you have to know how to use CSS selectors. I almost never use `getElement...` functions any more.) There are also functions that use [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath), though this is a bit more advanced subject.

Once you have the node, you can change its content using e.g. `.textContent` or `.innerHTML` properties, the former being for plain text, the latter for HTML.

For example, if this is the only `span` on the page, this suffices:

```js
document.querySelector('span').textContent = "Result";
```

```html
<span></span>
```

If on the other hand you have more of them, you would need some way to target the correct one. I will also demonstrate how you can style it using HTML:

```js
const node = document.querySelector('#result_goes_here');
node.innerHTML = "<strong>Result</strong> in bold!";
```

```html
<span id="result_goes_here"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to add the result inside the HTML SPAN and not in the alert box. You can do it something like this:

document.getElementById("span_ID").innerHTML = the_variable_result_here;

Hope that helps!